# Given a list of words, what regular expression will match on nth letter being x and nth to last letter being y?

Tags: regex

I want to understand how to create a regular expression which will match a set of words, where the nth letter is 'X', and the nth to last letter is 'Y'.

For example:

where 1st letter is f, and second to last letter is s:
fish -- MATCH
fashion -- NO MATCH
first -- MATCH

I have no attempts as I don't know where to start.

Comment: While this question may not confuse me, it might some others. Could you provide some word examples of what you want matched and not matched? Also any attempt you have tried?

Comment: Regex is about building patterns. Break what you want down into pieces and look for the regex matcher. For example, you want the _start of the string_ to be _f_ followed by _any number of letters_, followed by _s_, followed by _exactly one more letter_, and then the _end of the string_. (Replace start/end of string with _word boundaries_ if each entry is not on its own line.)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a starting point:

```
/(.{0}f.*s.{1})\s/gU
```

Matches fish and first but not fashion. [Example](https://regex101.com/r/dP9yQ8/1).

Explanation:

```
(...) - capture group
.{0}  - match anything zero times (in case you want to match something where the first letter is not at the start of the string
f     - match "f" literally
.*    - match anything
s     - match "s" literally
.{1}  - match anything once (this means that "s" would be second to last in the string)
\s    - for example only in your test data block. You could substitute this for an EOL delimiter e.g. ^
```